# Finding the first 3 terms of a power series... I am confused as to whether I can just plug numbers in or if there is more.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

The power series $J_0$= $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n}}{(n!)^22^{2n}}$$

Ive plugged in n=0,1,2 and have gotten    1-$\frac{x^2}{4}$+$\frac{x^4}{64}$

Is this all that is required?

The question is stated as "Find the first three terms of the power series for $J_0$  "

Comment: Yes, thats all !

Comment: Oh great, thank you for your quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's all there is to it! As you said, plugging in $n=0,1,2$, the series is;

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n}}{(n!)^22^{2n}}=1-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^{4}}{64}+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{6}\right)$$

Comment: is it important to write that last term with the O?

Comment: No, it's just notation to represents that all the other terms in the series have $x$ raised to a power of $6$ or more. The first $3$ terms of the series are the ones you wrote out and the big O just represents all the rest.

Comment: Yes, otherwise you couldn’t say “$=$”. You could write “$+\cdots$” instead, but this is more informative about what the remaining omitted terms are. I suppose one alternative would be to write “$\approx$” instead of “$=$”, then you could leave the tail off.

Comment: Okay thank you.

Comment: You're right, it is important for equality, but it isn't important for just writing down the first $3$ terms on their own, sorry for my lack of clarity.

Comment: @CoffeeCrow : Agreed